# Can't login with spring security in Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to login in my application with spring security, but it gives me an error. Also, I'm storing my password in data base in bcrypted form. In associate table I have got userid and roleid. But I can't login. What I've missed?
User table in mysql
[image]
user_role table in mysql
[image]
role table in mysql
[image]

Here is my login.html page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Spring Security Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/login.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <img th:src="@{/images/login.jpg}" class="img-responsive center-block" width="300" height="300" alt="Logo"/>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" class="form-signin">
        <h3 class="form-signin-heading" th:text="Welcome"></h3>
        <br/>

        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" th:placeholder="Email"
               class="form-control"/> <br/>
        <input type="password" th:placeholder="Password"
               id="password" name="password" class="form-control"/> <br/>

        <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
            <p style="font-size: 20; color: #FF1C19;">Email or Password invalid, please verify</p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
               value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit"
                th:text="Login"></button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my SecurityConfiguration class

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String USERS_QUERY = "select user_id, email, password from user where email=? ";
    private static final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?";
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/clients").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/clients")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
```

Here is my UserServiceImpl class.

```
   @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

User model class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

And Role class

```
    @Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "roleId")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've updated security configuration class, declaring bcrypt encoder here

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String USERS_QUERY = "select user_id, email, password, enabled from user where email=? ";
    private static final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?";
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/clients").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/clients")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

Also, I've updated my model. I've added `enabled` field that is `int`

```
    @Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "flatsender")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private int enabled;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Comment: Which error did you face?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, I can't login in my application. Incorrect login or password only

Comment: In my case I added an extra field in user table `enabled` and setting `1` means active user. User query will be `"select user_id, email, password,enabled from user where email=? ";` . I think the problem is in `bCryptPasswordEncoder` but for ensure everything please do that first and let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, i have done `enabled` field like TINYINT in mysql and Boolean in java model. But still have same result

Comment: Create a `passwordEncoder` bean and set it in `authbuilder` like that
`@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }` and set `.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, same result. check updates pls

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, also, while starting an application, i see this objects in debug

Comment: You put `.passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);` rather I suggest `.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154856/discussion-between-serg-shapoval-and-ataur-rahman-munna).